# Ubuntu 22.04 reboot randomly when ethernet is plugged

Tags: networking, ethernet, reboot

i have a new Asus TUF laptop, i installed Ubuntu 22.04 on it from a usb device. Wifi and wired internet connection seems to work properly but, when the ethernet cable is plugged on, ubuntu reboot randomly.

I don't understand why and i don't know where to look on logs to understand what happen.

Any idea ?

laptop : ASUS TUF A15, AMD RYZEN 7 6000 SERIES

Comment: Look at the system logs just before the crash: `sudo journalctl  -b -1`. Does it crash when you wiggle the cable? That would point to an intermittent hardware problem.

Comment: My laptop just reboot now (17h12)

```juin 26 17:09:52 DarkTeranga15A systemd[6338]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
juin 26 17:09:52 DarkTeranga15A dbus-daemon[6361]: [session uid=1000 pid=6361] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Extract'
juin 26 17:09:52 DarkTeranga15A systemd[6338]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.```

Nothing just before the reboot ... nothing when i wiggle the cable ..